# 66MB Tab Delimited File

Tags: c#

I have a big tab-delimited file, 66MB, and would like to know what the best approach would be to extract the data:

- Do I use a text parser? Will it cause any memory problems?
- Do I import it into SQL Server
- Do I break it up into smaller chunks?

What is the best way to deal with such a big file in an efficient way?

Comment: Sure way to atleast get your question read with that catchy question heading.

Comment: IMO 66MB is not that much considering the current systems

Comment: 66MB is not that large. Any modern system will deal with it no problem. What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: Rows of product data which used an Access db before and is now a tab-delimited file. Need to read the data and populate some fields, and I will run it in a production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can never be sure that the file will not grow in size over time, the most convenient way to do it would be to read the file line by line and process the contents.

Answer (score 1):

A 66MB should be relatively insignificant for any modern system to handle.  You'll have no trouble using File.ReadAllLines() or working with the entire 66MB file loaded into memory.

The real thing to consider is what is in the 66mb file?  Is it one thing?  A list of 10,000 things?  If you can work with individual 'items' (like, for example, one line) at a time, you can read one line at a time.  If it's 66MB on one line, you can read a certain number of bytes from the file at a time.

When you want to insert the data into a relational database; how you intend to use it will determine how to insert it.  If it's really just a 66mb chunk of data that doesn't make sense to break up; most databases have a type that will hold 66mb without any trouble (IE BLOB).